# GNU version issue with gnu++0x standard

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, gnu

I need to compile code with two compiler versions:

g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3

g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

I have a piece of code in a header file like this:

```
template <RealType> class Constant {
   ...
   /*constexpr*/ static const RealType Pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751;
   ...
};
```

If I build the code using `constexpr` with `g++ -std=gnu++0x` it works for version 4.7.3. But with version 4.6.3. building *.cpp files that include the header file fails with:

```
error: both ‘const’ and ‘constexpr’ cannot be used here
```

However, if I don't use `constexpr` version 4.6.3 complains:

```
error: ‘constexpr’ needed for in-class initialisation of static data member ‘const double Constant<double>::Pi’
```

Is there a workaround for that?

Btw, the code builds fine if I omit `-std=gnu++0x` (and of course `constexpr`)

Comment: Are you sure to enable all warnings and `-pedantic` when you say "the code builds fine"?

Comment: You realize that GCC 4.6.3 supports less C++11 than 4.7.3, yes?

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, I do. But there are other factors as well. It's a bigger project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `const` is redundant for variables. Just `constexpr`, like so:

```
static constexpr RealType Pi = 3.14;
```

---

In C++14 you can even say,

```
template <typename T> constexpr Pi = T(3.14);
```

and use it as `Pi<double>` etc.

Comment: I guess, I could have figured out this on my own. Thanks.